# VS Code Doesn't Understand Shorthand React.Fragment Tags In Tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I've setup a create-react-app with TypeScript:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

However, whenever I try to use a shorthand <React.Fragment> tag, like:

```
function App() {
return (<>
    <header>Hello World</header>
</>);
}
```

VS Code complains that it's an error:

```
Type expected. (6:13)
  4 | 
  5 | function App() {
> 6 |     return <><header>Hello World</header></>;
    |             ^
  7 | }
  8 | 
  9 | export default App;
```

It is of course understood & rendered just fine by React itself.  Why is VS Code indicating this as an error, & how might I be able to fix it?

Comment: This is not an issue with VS Code specifically, what extensions do you have installed?

Comment: Good call - It was caused by Prettier Now.  If you'd like to post an answer, I'll accept :)

Comment: Done, thank you! Glad I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not default behavior of VS Code. It is likely caused by an extension.

Comment: It was caused by Prettier Now, a code beautifier.  Thanks for the quick reply!